# Joining an array that contains multiple spaces eliminates duplicate spaces in Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-chrome

Why do you suppose the following behavior is different in Chrome?  V8 bug?  It does not seem to conform to the [ES specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.join).

In Safari:

```
['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('')
> "A     B"
```

In Firefox:

```
['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('')
> "A     B"
```

In Chrome (version  46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)):

```
['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('')
> "A B"
```

Comment: If it doesn't conform to the spec it is a bug and you should write a bug report.

Comment: Yes will report; was hoping it was perhaps an oversight on my part.

Comment: Works on Chrome 48:['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('')
"A     B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Chrome formats output in the console. I'm not sure specifically what it is and I can't find this documented, but it is easy to prove that the true string value is retained:

```
> ['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('').split('')
["A", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "B"]
```

You can use `console.log` to print out the unformatted string value.

Comment: Tricky.  Wish there was a way for me to turn this off.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested on Chrome 46, 47, 48 and it works.

```
['A', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'B'].join('')
"A     B"
```

A quick check [this demo](https://jsbin.com/beloso/latest) shows that it works too.